# How can I check in the userNotificationCenter which identifier was used to trigger local notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, identifier, unusernotificationcenter

I want to do different things for different local notifications which is why I am wondering how I can detect which identifier was used to send the local notification.

I want to do my action in the "willPresent notification" function and not in the "didReceive Response" function. Thank you for your help!

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the `notification's` `identifier` in `userNotificationCenter(_: willPresent: withCompletionHandler)` using,

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let identifier = notification.request.identifier //here...
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])        
}
```